# PyTelegramAPI Sending a message with an attachment image

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I have been using PyTelegramAPI for some time and I am looking to send text with an attachment below, which would be a .png Image.

I can't find a particular link in the docs to help me do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look far enough....

.send_photo() method has a caption kwarg in...

Answer (score 1):

Try this, note that the path structure will depend on your operating system as well as where the file is actually located:

```
def telegram_bot_sendphoto(bot_message, image_path):

    bot_token = TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN #make sure to switch these out 
    bot_chat_id = TELEGRAM_CHANNEL
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token, parse_mode=None)
    # photo = open('/images/sample.jpg', 'rb') #2 possible ways of writing the file path
    # photo = "https://example.com/image.pnh"
    photo = open(image_path, 'rb') #open the photo for reading
    status = bot.send_photo(bot_chat_id, photo, bot_message, timeout=100) #now send the photo with a message and a timeout (how long to wait before giving up if the send fails)
```